# always detects same pin as HIGH even when its not connected

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, analogread

Im practicing with an arduino UNO board (I'm a begginer) and I'm trying to turn some LED's on depending on which analog pin is connected to 5V.
Here's my code:

```
int statusLed = 11;
int out1 = 2;
int out2 = 3;
int out3 = 4;
int out4 = 5;
int in1 = A0;
int in2 = A1;
int in3 = A2;
int in4 = A3;
int statusLedBrightness = 3;
int incBrillo = 3;
int fadeDelay = 5;

void blinkFade(int pin){
  analogWrite(pin, statusLedBrightness);
  statusLedBrightness = statusLedBrightness + incBrillo;
  if (statusLedBrightness <= 0 || statusLedBrightness >= 255){
    incBrillo = -incBrillo;   
  } 
  delay(fadeDelay);
  }

void wait(){  
  digitalWrite(out1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(out2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(out3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(out4, LOW);
  blinkFade(statusLed);
}



void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(out1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(out2,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(out3,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(out4,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in1, INPUT);
  pinMode(in2, INPUT);
  pinMode(in3, INPUT);
  pinMode(in4, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  if (analogRead(in1)>=500){
    Serial.println("1: ");
    Serial.println(analogRead(in1)); //Print "1" and the read of pin A0
    turnOff();
    digitalWrite(out1,HIGH);
  }
  else if (analogRead(in2)>=500){
    Serial.println("2: ");
    Serial.println(analogRead(in2));//Print "2" and the read of pin A1
    turnOff();
    digitalWrite(out2,HIGH);
  }
  else if (analogRead(in3)>=500){
    Serial.println("3: ");
    Serial.println(analogRead(in3));//Print "3" and the read of pin A2
    turnOff();
    digitalWrite(out3,HIGH);
  }
  else if (analogRead(in4)>=500){
    Serial.println("4: ");
    Serial.println(analogRead(in4));//Print "4" and the read of pin A3
    turnOff();
    digitalWrite(out4,HIGH);
  }
  else{
    Serial.println("Stand By");
    wait();
  }

}
```

The problem Im having is when I connect a wire from 5V to any analog pin (A0 to A3) it always runs this segment of code:

```
Serial.println("1: ");
Serial.println(analogRead(in1));
turnOff();
digitalWrite(out1,HIGH);
```

By my understanding it's detecting as if it always was A0 the one that is connected to 5V but i dont understand why is this happening or how to solve it.

This is a screen capture of serial monitor when 5V is connected to pin A2. It should print "3:" and the reading
[[image]]
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8izJq.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not showing your schematic but I'm sure that you are simply leaving the Ax pins OPEN when you are not connecting them to your +V line.  In that case they are "floating" and as such they can float HIGH or LOW or just about anywhere.  What's happening is that when you hook up +V to any of them, that has the side-effect of pulling at least A0 HIGH along with it since you have allowed it to float.

Two things to do here:

1. Don't allow lines to float and expect deterministic behavior.  Tie them to +V or to GROUND when you are not using them.
2. Pull the Ax lines to +V or GND via a resistor like 10K Ohms.  This will prevent them from floating and will give you predictable results.

Comment: that was it, adding resistors to pull Ax lines to GND did it. Thanks!